# Minecraft world's specific object selection

Tags: materials, objects

[image]

Hi,

I am having a problem with selecting specific objects like grass or leaves or flowers. When I try to select a specific object the world gets selected. Can anyone tell me how to select a separate group of grasses of leaves?

Thank you!

Comment: It's probably one model. You have to separate them in Edit Mode.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Most likely as visible in the picture, you have one object, with the different parts of the world having their materials assigned. My suggestion would be to select the object, go in edit mode and press "P" separate by **materials**.

Comment: thanks, I got my answer. You helped a lot!!